# Scientific notation for ipywidgets slider

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

In `ipywidgets`, how do I use scientific notation for large values of slider? Say if I have something like:

`FloatSlider(min=1e7, max=1e9, step=1e7)`

The display on the slider would be full of zeros. Can I somehow switch that to a scientific notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the help you will find a section saying:

```
readout_format : str
    default is '.2f', specifier for the format function used to represent
    slider value for human consumption, modeled after Python 3's format
    specification mini-language (PEP 3101).
```

So:

```
FloatSlider(min=1e7, max=1e9, step=1e7, readout_format='.2e')
```

should do the job.